# Unicode, ASCII, and Regex Won't Work

Tags: python, unicode, encoding, utf-8

So I am using Python 3.6.something and I've been trying to figure out this completely intuitive Unicode/ASCII nightmare. I am trying to save the text from a webpage into a file, and parse it using Regex later.

When I try to read the file and parse it, I need to find the pattern:

```
Note 1 –
```

Which is apparently different from:

```
Note 1 -
```

I keep getting the error:

```
SyntaxError: Non-UTF-8 code starting with '\x96' in file C:\Users\Steve\eclipse-workspace\scraper\BeautifulSoupTest.py on line 28, but no encoding declared; see http://python.org/dev/peps/pep-0263/ for details
```

on the RegEx that I am trying to do. This is really strange since '\x96' is an Unicode character from what I've seen online. Something is going on with Unicode or ASCII and I have no clue what it is. I also can't remove the '\x96' character with a replace() either, it gives the same error. Can anyone help?

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
from urllib.request import urlopen
import re

def downloadCleanText(url, year):
    urlObject = urlopen(url)

    rawHTML = urlObject.read()


    cleanedText = BeautifulSoup(rawHTML, 'html.parser').body.getText()

    outputFile = open(str(year) + '.txt', 'w')

    outputFile.write(cleanedText)

    outputFile.close()

def pullNote1(year):
    inputFile = open(str(year) + '.txt', 'r')

    inData = inputFile.read()

    outData = re.findall('Note 1 –(.*?)Note 2 ', inData)

    print(outData)

    inputFile.close()

downloadCleanText('https://www.sec.gov/Archives/edgar/data/320193/000032019317000070/a10-k20179302017.htm#s2A826F0B8B5755F787D29B5B8C8C7D16', 2000)
pullNote1(2000)
```

Comment: The exception message is **very clear**. Did you follow the URL and add the source code encoding declaration to your code?

Comment: `\x96` is **not** an ASCII character. ASCII runs from 0x00 through to 0x7F.

Comment: "The URL" being the one in the error message; http://python.org/dev/peps/pep-0263/

Comment: You have a [U+2013 EN DASH](https://codepoints.net/U+2013) character in your regex, and saved your file encoded as [Windows Codepage 1252](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Windows-1252), where the EN DASH encodes to 0x96. You also used a *byte string*, not a Unicode string. Unless your input data is actually encoded as CP1252 as well, your regex won't match.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No, 0x96 is **not** an [ASCII codepoint](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ASCII). The ASCII standard defines only 7 bit codepoints, so from 0x00 through to 0x7F. Nor is 0x96 a valid [UTF-8 byte sequence](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/UTF-8).

You most likely have saved your source code as [Windows Codepage 1252](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Windows-1252), where 0x96 is the [U+2013 EN DASH](https://codepoints.net/U+2013) codepoint (all codepages between 1250 and 1258 do, but 1252 is the most widely used). So, following the exception message you can make the error go away by adding:

```
# encoding: cp1252
```

at the top of the file. Or you could configure your editor to save the file as UTF-8 instead (at which point the byte sequence 0xE2 0x80 0x93 will be written to represent that codepoint).

Alternatively, use only ASCII characters in your source code by using a `\uhhhh` escape sequence in your string literal:

```
outData = re.findall('Note 1 \u2013(.*?)Note 2 ', inData)
```

You may want to read up on Unicode and Python, I strongly recommend Ned Batchelder's [*Pragmatic Unicode*](https://nedbatchelder.com/text/unipain.html).

Comment: Thanks for your help, I have already been going through Ned Batchelder's material, albeit slowly. I never would have guessed about the source encoding though and that worked perfectly.